# Python Webscraper - AttributeError: 'HTTPResponse' object has no attribute 'open'

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new-ish to python and am trying to write a bot that scrapes cryptocurrency prices from coinbase.

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/'
uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.open()
uClient.close()
```

This is what I have so far. Any advice or better ways to achieve what I am doing would be greatly appreciated. Any explanations would be helpful also. I have been following youtube videos to do this and I am not sure if I really "get the picture." Thanks in advance!

Comment: do some searching on google on how to do this then come back here with specific questions about issues you might be running into implementing it

Answer (score 0):

From the docs https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/') as response:
   html = response.read()
```

or just change

```
page_html = uClient.open()
```

to

```
page_html = uClient.read()
```